# Store in a variable monitoring result of dd to use it in c++

Tags: ubuntu, dd, c++

I use this to monitor dd when i copy files.

```
sudo dd if=$source of=$pathToUsb bs=4M conv=fdatasync status=progress 2>&1 | stdbuf -o1 tr '\r' '\n' | stdbuf -o1 cut -d' ' -f1 | sed -u 's/[a-z]*//g'
```

so i've something like this

3078619136

3103784960

3133145088

3158310912

and so on.

I would like to store the result in a variable to use it in c++

I thinked to code like this in c++

```
system("while read line;do export line; done < <(sudo dd if=$source of=$pathToUsb bs=4M conv=fdatasync status=progress 2>&1 | stdbuf -o1 tr '\\r' '\\n' | stdbuf -o1 cut -d' ' -f1 | sed -u 's/[a-z]*//g'");
```

but error is :
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

What can i do to store in a variable and use it in c++ code ?

Comment: Welcome, you didn't close the 2nd parenthesis: `system("... (sudo...");`

Comment: You could read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), perhaps use [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) and take inspiration from the source code of [fish](https://fishshell.com/) or of [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)

Comment: You're using `bash` syntax from `sh`

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity thanks i fix it

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch thanks will see

Comment: bash from sh ? yes i understand... so what can i do ?

Comment: not sure why you use dd at all when you have C